# Cannot access images in Angular when using Azure Application Gateway with Path-based routing

Tags: angular, azure, single-page-application, azure-application-gateway

I have an Azure Application Gateway configured with Path-based routing.

There are multiple Angular applications and I am running them using the following path rules:

1. /app1/ (Backend pool: app1_pool)
2. /app2/ (Backend pool: app2_pool)

But cannot access assets (images) in them.

Angular configuration -> package.json:

```
...
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
...
```

And, publishing the application using the following command:

```
ng build --configuration production --base-href \"/app1\" --deploy-url \"/app1/\""
```

### The problem

The problem is that I cannot access images located in the "assets" folder.

I can only access them if they are located in the root folder.

**So, is there a way to access images located in the "assets" folder?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the Backend settings configuration.

There are two ways to make Angular application work when using Path-based routing:

1. Create path mapping in the App Settings -> Configuration ([Example for the Windows-based App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal))
2. Override the path in the Application Gateway backend settings with "/"

I used the second option. This rewrites requests to start with "/" when forwarded to the backend pool ([Source](https://www.domstamand.com/path-based-routing-in-azure-application-gateway-with-azure-webapps/)).

[image: Override path]